# How can I set the FlexBox.alignItems to flex_end programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-flexboxlayout

I know how to do it in xml

```
app:alignItems="flex_start"
```

But I don't know were to find the reference to flex_end programmatically.

For example this code (in kotlin) makes the entire layout blank.  But when I search the project for "flex_box"  the only place i see it is int the R file. 
So how do I set alignItems = .flex_end?

```
init {
    flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
    flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
    alignItems = R.id.flex_end
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using

```
    JustifyContent.FLEX_END
```

Comment: I wish the FlexboxLayout class does not have a ALIGN_ITEMS_FLEX_END variable inside it.

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: Sorry, in the class FlexboxLayout there is no variable called ALIGN_ITEMS_FLEX_END